# webpack: How do you bundle all scss files into a single main.css file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm making a react app, so my file structure has a components folders with folders for each component. Each component folder contains a `ComponentName.js` and `ComponentName.scss` file.  How do I configure my webpack, so that I can just add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />` in the head of my index.html?

I have the ExtractTextPlugin in my webpack config, but I'm not sure if I should be using it because I'm not requiring any css files.  I am also looking for a scss loader, but can only find the sass loader, so am I supposed to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make this work with [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin).  This can take your index.html as in input template and automatically inject script and link tags into it.  So it could inject your main.css and your js bundle into the html page for you.  It works great with the ExtractTextPlugin.

I have something similar with the following config:

My loader:

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /critical\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css', 'postcss', 'sass'])
  }]
}
```

My Plugins:

```
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('css/critical.css'),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html'
  })
]
```

With this approach I would require the scss file in your code, just do it in your app component and you could let your scss file import other scss files. I am using the sass-loader combined with post-loader and css-loader. I use the post loader so I can use the autoprefixer.  I have a project doing something similar to this for an Esri based application, except I use a custom plugin to inline the css into the head and add a style tag for below the fold content. You can find it here https://github.com/Robert-W/esri-redux.

NOTE: I am still learning webpack myself so this may not be the best setup but it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webpack-text-extract-pluggin that is in charge of compiling all css files and bundling them in an index.css file.

Also note that you'll need to install sass-loader too in order to compile the scss.

In the webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
config = {
    ..., 
    plugins: [
        ...,
        new ExtractTextPlugin('index.css')
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">
```

In any Javascript file that gets through webpack:

```
require("./styles/my-custom-file.scss");
```